# Backups marked incomplete, but seem to be full backups, while using vultr VPS with WHM Cpanel destination Amazon S3. How do I resolve this?

Tags: amazon-s3, backup, cpanel, vps, whm

I'm backing up 35 or so accounts to Amazon S3. The connection is good, all of the backup files are being written, but afterwards in the backup folder I have a tiny file named 'backup incomplete' and you open it, it shows the date. The WHM/Cpanel side obviously is marking this incomplete, but I'm not sure why as the file sizes seem to be identical to the actual on-server data. I've double checked that there are no disk space issues both on the server and on the destination S3 bucket. I've verified that the backup configuration is correct, and validated the connection to the S3 bucket. I am using vultr VPS for hosting, if that matters. I do have VPS snapshots taking place but they happen about 5 hours after the S3 backup starts. I have 5 other vultr VPS servers setup with this same configuration with no issues. Any ideas on where to look to find why this is happening and resolve it?

Comment: I would post this on https://superuser.com/ or perhaps https://serverfault.com/ since it does not appear to be about programming

Answer (score 1):

OK! So I found my issue. Exporting of a mySQL database was failing during the backup. I found this by reviewing the cpanel log files found in `/usr/local/cpanel/logs/cpbackup`

For more information about cpanel logs visit: 
`https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/The+cPanel+Log+Files`

Answer (score 0):

Any empty database in a user account will cause this. In the log it looks like:

```
[2022-01-11 07:47:45 -0500] Determining mysql dbs...The system failed to fetch the status of the database “foo_bar” because of an error: (XID bazqux) The system received an error from the “MySQL” database “mysql”: ER_BAD_DB_ERROR (Unknown database 'foo_bar')
...
[2022-01-11 07:47:45 -0500] mysqldump: Got error: 1049: "Unknown database 'foo_bar'" when selecting the database
```

Trawling through a log file is tedious, but some other keywords besides "error" can be found here: https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/1500001997102-Backups-PartialFailure-backup-incomplete-in-our-backup-directory-and-the-old-backup-won-t-delete-prune